# Semantical Error in symfony2 while fetching the data

Tags: symfony

I am trying to write a web service to fetch the category list and all the business under that category in an nested array fashion.

I am getting an Semantical Error saying :

```
{
  code: 500
  message: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'StreetBumbApiBundle:Buss_owner': Error: Class 'StreetBumb\ApiBundle\Entity\Buss_owner' is not defined."
}
```

I already defined the entity in the controller, i dont know why it is showing this error.

This is how my controller's function looks like:

```
public  function getCategoryAction(){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $pro = $em->getRepository('StreetBumbApiBundle:Category')
        ->getBusinessByCategory();
    //return $pro;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($pro as $p)
    {
        $data['category'][$i]['id'] = $p->getId();
        $data['category'][$i]['Name'] = $p->getCatName();
        //$result[$i] = $p->getId();

        $catId = $p->getId();

        $business = $em->createQuery('SELECT b FROM StreetBumbApiBundle:Buss_owner b WHERE b.catId = :catId')->setParameter('catId', $catId);
        $result = $business->getResult();
        foreach($result as $r)
        {
            $data['business'][$i]['id'][] = $r->getId();
        }
        $i++;

    }
    return $data;
}
```

Please guide if anyone have idea.. Thanx

**UPDATE:** 
Buss_owner Entity:

```
<?php

 namespace StreetBumb\ApiBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Buss_owner
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 *        @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StreetBumb\ApiBundle\Entity\Buss_ownerRepository")
 */
 class Buss_owner
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phno", type="integer")
 */
private $phno;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fbId", type="integer")
 */
private $fbId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="uniqueId", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $uniqueId;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="catId", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="Buss_owner")
 */
private $catId;

public function __construct() {
    $this->catId = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set phno
 *
 * @param integer $phno
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setPhno($phno)
{
    $this->phno = $phno;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phno
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPhno()
{
    return $this->phno;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set catId
 *
 * @param integer $catId
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setCatId($catId)
{
    $this->catId = $catId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get catId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getCatId()
{
    return $this->catId;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set uniqueId
 *
 * @param string $uniqueId
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setUniqueId($uniqueId)
{
    $this->uniqueId = $uniqueId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get uniqueId
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUniqueId()
{
    return $this->uniqueId;
}

/**
 * Set fbId
 *
 * @param integer $fbId
 * @return Buss_owner
 */
public function setFbId($fbId)
{
    $this->fbId = $fbId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fbId
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getFbId()
{
    return $this->fbId;
}

}
```

Comment: Show us your `Buss_owner` entity please.

Comment: @BentCoder Updated my question with `Buss_owner` entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the underscore in the entity name.

Doctrine's naming convention is to use CamelCase which it then converts to underscores in the database. Due to this behind the scenes magic, underscores can cause problems in entity names.

Try changing the entity class name to `BussOwner` and calling this in the controller. If you can't change the table name you can handle this by modifying the entity annotation to:

```
@ORM\Table(name="buss_owner")
```